# What's a better method for processing these hosts & network ranges into a network hierarchy dictionary?

Tags: python, recursion, hierarchy

Please ignore the nonsensical CIDRs / IP ranges, I can't bear subnetting tonight.

Let's say I have a list of host IPs and their network ranges, like this:

```
ip_sets = [{
    "host": "4.4.4.254", 
    "ipLow": "4.4.4.0",
    "ipHigh": "4.4.4.255"
}, ...]
```

and I want to organize them into a network hierarchy like so, with the biggest networks holding all small smaller networks, *without a circular structure*:

```
{
    "4.4.4.0/8": {
        "network": <network obj>,
        "hosts": { "4.4.4.254": <ip obj> }
        "subnets" : { "4.4.4.0/32": { ... and so on ... } }
    }
}
```

Hosts should be placed in the lowest containing network.

I'm using the [native ip address utility in python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html). My game plan was to:

#### 1. Generate a dictionary of all networks, without network relationships considered yet:

```
network_dict = {}
for index, ip_set in ip_sets:
    start_ip_str = ip_set["ipLow"]
    end_ip_str = ip_set["ipHigh"]
    host_ip_str = ip_set["host"]
    start_ip = ipaddress.IPv4Address(start_ip_str)
    end_ip = ipaddress.IPv4Address(end_ip_str)
    host_ip = ipaddress.IPv4Address(host_ip_str)
    networks = [ipaddr for ipaddr in ipaddress.summarize_address_range(start_ip, end_ip)]
    for network in networks:
        network_str = format(network)
        if network_str in network_dict:
            network_dict[network_str]["hosts"][host_ip_str] = host_ip
        else:
            network_dict[network_str] = {
                "network": network,
                "hosts": { host_ip_str: host_ip },
                "subnets": {},
                "supernets": {},
            }
```

#### 2. Recursively check if each network in the dictionary is a subnet of any other, using `.subnet_of`:

```
network_dict_keys = network_dict.keys()
for network1_key in network_dict_keys:
    for network2_key in network_dict_keys:
        network1 = network_dict[network1_key]
        network2 = network_dict[network2_key]
        if network1["network"].subnet_of(network2["network"]):
            network2["subnets"][network1_key] = network_dict[network1_key]
            network1["supernets"][network2_key] = network_dict[network2_key]
```

#### 3. Then go back through and recursively `copy.deepcopy()` / replace all network references in hierarchies without `supernets` keys and delete all networks with any keys in the `supernets` dict.

By copying references in a circular manner at first, then going back and cloning / deleting, I feel like the process is made a bit simpler than some alternatives I thought of.

But this method feels redundant and ugly. I'm not even sure it works properly.

#### What's a better way to do this?

Comment: see this https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-intervals/ your underlying data can be organized as that, flat list but pretty quick. At the face level do you need to provide something like addRange, DeleteRange, isInRange?

Comment: @BingWang No deving a network map UI